# How to get selected option text from a select box selenium node js

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, javascript

How to get the selected option's text using selenium webdriver node.js.
In java we can use getFirstSelectedOption but it is not working in node.js.
How it is possible?

Here is my sample code.

```
driver.get("url").then(function () {
                return driver.findElements(webdriver.By.className('test-class'))
            }).then(function (elements) {
                elements.forEach(function(el){
                    el.sendKeys('4');
                })
            }).then(function () {
                return driver.findElements(webdriver.By.className('test-class'))
            }).then(function (elements) {
                elements.forEach(function(el){
                    el.getFirstSelectedOption().getText().then(function(text){
                        assert.equal('4', text);
                    })
                });
```

Comment: @TESTasy please check the updated question.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`getAttribute()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver_exports_WebElement.html#getAttribute) on select elements, should look something like this in your case:

```
var element = driver.findElement(By.className('test-class')));
element.getAttribute('value').then(function(selected) {
  assert.equal('4', selected);
});
```

Comment: I just want selected option's text ? Is it possible?

Comment: @azhar - in Niels example, change `getAttribute('value')` to `getAttribute('text')`